# Do I need to validate poetry.lock files?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I use the `poetry.lock` file as the Source Of Truth in my build-chain, so I'd like to be sure that it is always reliable. Or in other words, given that none of my dependencies have released new versions, will adding and removing dependencies accumulate unnecessary artifacts in the lockfile?

In particular, after removing dependencies I've sometimes deleted the lockfile and re-generated it with `poetry lock` as a cautionary measure, but noticed that the result was always identical to the one I'd just deleted. Was this merely by chance, or is it guaranteed behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It is not guaranteed behavior. For example in one of our projects, we have the following in `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
django-storages = {version = "1.7.1",extras = ["boto3"]}
```

When I run `poetry lock` on this project right now, the resulting diff looks like the following, because we only specify which version of `django-storages` we want, but not which version of `boto3` it should use:

```
diff --git a/poetry.lock b/poetry.lock
index 6d542df..0ec8d23 100644
--- a/poetry.lock
+++ b/poetry.lock
@@ -77,10 +77,10 @@ marker = "extra == \"boto3\""
 name = "boto3"
 optional = false
 python-versions = "*"
-version = "1.9.189"
+version = "1.9.191"

 [package.dependencies]
-botocore = ">=1.12.189,<1.13.0"
+botocore = ">=1.12.191,<1.13.0"
 jmespath = ">=0.7.1,<1.0.0"
 s3transfer = ">=0.2.0,<0.3.0"

@@ -91,7 +91,7 @@ marker = "extra == \"boto3\""
 name = "botocore"
 optional = false
 python-versions = "*"
-version = "1.12.189"
+version = "1.12.191"

 [package.dependencies]
 docutils = ">=0.10"
@@ -359,8 +359,8 @@ category = "main"
 description = "Docutils -- Python Documentation Utilities"
 name = "docutils"
 optional = false
-python-versions = "*"
-version = "0.14"
+python-versions = ">=2.6, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*"
+version = "0.15.1"

 [[package]]
 category = "main"
```

Anything which is not specified in `pyproject.toml` will be updated when you run `poetry lock`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if your example describes the same issue that I mean. I'd assume that having secondary delendencies that get updated or changing which versions you want to nail down will have consequences when poetry lock is run.

Comment: What I am curious about is if running poetry lock right after adding or deleting something witb poetry can have an effect.

Comment: Yes, it might have an effect. Let's assume you run the following `poetry init && poetry add --extras boto django-storages`.

This results in pytz, sqlparse, boto and django and django-storages being installed.

All of those packages are locked in `poetry.lock`.

However, only `django-storages` is noted in `pyproject.toml`.

When you now run `poetry lock`, the existing lockfile will be dropped and all dependencies will be resolved again to their most recent version, which may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Poetry diffs are often hard to make sense of, and there's not much you can do about it.

In order to validate my dependency changes and to keep track of all changes, I've written a Github Action that will post a nicely readable summary of all the changes from poetry.lock to your pull requests. Maybe you will find this helpful: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/diff-poetry-lock